# Sending video data while recording using AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession, avcapture

Hai I am creating an iOS application for video streaming.
I never tried AVCaptureSession.
I want to send the video+audio data while recording, is it possible ? If so please help me to do that.

Or is there any way to get video data in some time interval (say 10sec), without breaking recording will I get recorded video data in every 10 seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a hesitant '*yes*'. You can get the video data from your AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate which responds to –captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection: This part is easy.

However this is *raw* video data and both audio and video. What it isn't is encoded frames suitable for streaming. For that, you need figure out a solution to encode and stream on your own.